# Unsubscribe from event handler C#, use default handler instead

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I am using CEF browser in my app. Now my issue is following.

You can for example create you own handler for file download dialog by this way.

```
browser.DownloadHandler = new MyOwnDownloadHandler();
```

Now MyOwnDownloadHandler have to implemet IDownloadHanler interface, which is following:

```
public interface IDownloadHandler
{
    void OnBeforeDownload(IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem,   IBeforeDownloadCallback callback);
    void OnDownloadUpdated(IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IDownloadItemCallback callback);
}
```

Now this is nice, I can do my own file download dialog and some other magic there. The problem I am facing is that I do not want to use this handler all the time. I want to switch between my handler and default handler. There is obviously some default handler, but I do not know how to restore it and disable mine.

How can I do this ? I cannot simply use += and -= to unsubscribe event.

Comment: Have you tried `browser.DownloadHandler = null;`?

Comment: :) Well it is working. Thank you. I was googling for some rocket science stuff and forgot to use brain. @adv12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
browser.DownloadHandler = null;
```